# Esconder PasswordChar no DbGrid Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, dbgrid

É possível esconder as senhas que são mostradas no meu `dbgrid`? Pois o mesmo `dbgrid` é usado para editar as senhas.

Comment: Podia dar mais detalhes do que precisa?